# bootstrap datepicker setDates issue [eternicode]

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have no idea why but

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDates', new Date(2011, 2, 5), new Date(2012, 2, 5));
```

does not set dates

I've created a plunk 
http://plnkr.co/edit/G3HFbA?p=preview

Comment: Do you have `jQuery` included? Nvm, you do, but they're included in the wrong order; `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` should be included **before** `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: updated but not the cause of the problem

Comment: Ok, that would fix other issues though :P Anyway, can you better define "refuse to do its work"?

Comment: component do no reflect changes; I expect the component to present selected dates inside the input fields also when clicked the input should present the selected but present the today date